# How did the Usher family get so rich?

Tags: the-fall-of-the-house-of-usher

The Usher family is presented as extremely rich and influential in the series. I only recall one time where a specific amount was mentioned and that was 4.5 billion dollars in the last episode. That wasn't necessarily the entire net worth of the family, but should give a rough estimate just how rich they were. There are also obvious parallels to real events and the Sackler family who owned Purdue. They were worth at least 13 billion dollars.

What I don't understand is how Roderick Usher got that rich given the events shown in the series. At the end it is shown that he managed to become CEO of Fortunato due to the schemes he and his sister performed. But while you can get quite wealthy by being CEO of a major company, this is still quite far from the wealth the Usher family is shown to have in the series. The entire time they're shown they are presented like the own the company, which also would fit much better to the real world events the series references. But I never noticed any point where it was actually stated that they own the company.

Did they actually own the company or not? If they did own it, how did they manage that? And if not, how did they become as wealthy as they are shown in the show?

Answer (score 4):

We know that Fortunado was a publicly traded company. Roderick was the CEO of Fortunado. Madeline was the COO. Together they would most likely own shares in the company as is usual in those positions. Perhaps with the help of Verna, they were able to acquire a significant portion of the company over time perhaps even becoming majority shareholders, but they never mention that so we can't be for certain.

We do know that between the time Roderick became CEO and the present, the company grew considerably. His invention Ligodone became a vastly popular painkiller. It was above-and-beyond their most popular product, and it skyrocketed Fortunado's revenues. We also know that Roderick and Madeline were both able to start other business ventures both in and out of Fortunado that were guaranteed to succeed without the need to worry about regulations because that was part of their deal with Verna. This allowed them to cut significant corners and maximize profits. This success would of course lead to multi-million dollar bonuses for the executives. Roderick and Madeline would then invest this money in other things which, again, were guaranteed to succeed thanks to Verna.

So this repeated cycle of success over time would of course lead to a massive amount of wealth. Even if they didn't own a significant portion of the company. As far as Fortunado's board was concerned, Roderick was an excellent CEO.